# How to add subviews to a UIButton via Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, storyboard

Is it not possible to add a subview to a UIButton via Storyboard? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704755/adding-a-subview-to-uibutton) suggests it is possible in code, but how do you do it via Storyboard? Dragging a UIView to become a child of a UIButton isn't working.

Aware of simple workarounds like creating a parent UIView to hold the UIButton and subviews, but this question focuses on whether it's possible to add subviews to a UIButton inside of Storyboard.

Comment: Refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374860/how-can-i-addsubview-to-uibutton-in-interface-builder

Comment: @schmidt9 yes but that answer suggests it's not possible. are you saying this is the only way to do it?

Comment: Yes, this is impossible, just do what they suggest in that answer :)

Comment: @schmidt9 ok please post this as an answer

Comment: you also can try to edit storyboard as an xml and put the subview manually inside UIButton declaration. 99% it wouldn't work but you can try)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add subviews to `UIButton` in Interface Builder, use `UIView` as container, then add `UIButton` and whatever you want to it. Note, eg. you can place a `UILabel` on top of the button and if you do not set `userInteractionEnabled = YES` for that label, your button will still response to touch events. Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374860/how-can-i-addsubview-to-uibutton-in-interface-builder) answer.